# Nested update an array of objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have a problem to writing a mongodb query to nested updating an array of objects.
My current document in the collection is like this:

```
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "data": {
      "arr_1": [
        {
          "inner_arr_1": [
            {
              "aid": "111",
              "ans": "def"
            },
            {
              "aid": "222",
              "ans": "def"
            },
          ],
          "inner_arr_2": [
            {
              "aid": "333",
              "ans": "def"
            },
            {
              "aid": "444",
              "ans": "def"
            },
          ],
          "inner_arr_3": [
            {
              "aid": "555",
              "ans": "def"
            },
            {
              "aid": "666",
              "ans": "def"
            },
          ]
        },
        
      ]
    },
    "name": "John"
  }
```

I want to write an API endpint by express in nodejs to nested update this document.
The post body of the endpoint is like:

```
req.body = {
  "_id": 1,
  "data": {
      "arr_1": [
        {
          "inner_arr_1": [
            {
              "aid": "111",
              "ans": "new val"
            }
          ],
          "inner_arr_3": [
            {
              "aid": "666",
              "ans": "new val"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Anyone can help me to write a query to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: When you say "update", do you want to **add** or **replace** `inner_arr_1` and `inner_arr_3` inside `arr_1`?

Comment: Also, assuming `name` is not being enforced to be unique, you'll need to add `_id` or some other unique identifier to target a specific existing document in your query.

Comment: @rantao
No, I won't replace `inner_arr_1` and `inner_arr_3`. I just want to update `ans` filed of objects in `inner_arr_1` and `inner_arr_3` based on `aid` filtering.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MIIRI3sKFI7

Comment: @R2D2 Thanks, man. But in this solution, you must write hardcode `inner_arr_1` for $set. I try to find a dynamic solution.